# Audio input for Apple MacBook Air M1

Tags: mac

There is no input on my Apple MacBook Air M1. From sound it only has internal mic with no external option. Tried recording to Garage Band but cannot record.

Comment: There is no audio input jack on an MacBook Air. How are you inputing audio? Unless you purchase an external USB C to audio jack adapter there is no way to hook up an external audio source.

Comment: Please rephrase in the form of a question. Right now it just sounds like a complaint, not a question.

Comment: Your headphone jack has analog mono mic input (so you can use the mic in a smartphone headset plugged into that jack). You can probably get an adapter that would allow you to use it with other mics as long as they don't require phantom power. Most people recording on Macs use audio interface boxes that connect over USB.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Bluetooth audio adaper](https://www.amazon.com/bluetooth-audio-adapter/s?k=bluetooth%20audio%20adapter), or, as suggested in comments, a [USB-to-audio adapter](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=usb%20audio%20adapter&ref=nb_sb_noss_1).

That said, *some* users of the MacBook Air M1 have found [Bluetooth connectivity issues](https://appleinsider.com/articles/20/11/25/some-m1-mac-owners-encounter-bluetooth-connectivity-issues).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...That means I would have to use an A to D converter?

Comment: I want to record an LP (example)..   I go from the audio outs of the stereo into the 3 1/2 input on the right side.   I could do that with my old Mac...going to Garage Band.  It seems Mac cheated on this computer by not having a line input (only internal mic)